# Toggle slideDown/slideUp multiple states on page load

Tags: jquery, toggle

When the page loads, there are elements that I want showing the content and others hiding the content. When the user clicks the header, the element will toggle between hiding and showing depending on what their current state is. The script that I have written works, but it has a quark and I feel it needs to have an if/else to determine the state of the .content to determine the click. Currently it requires the user to click twice on the hidden element to display .content.

```
 $('#services .content').hide();
 $('.header').toggle(function() {
    $(this)
       .addClass('active')
       .next('.content').slideUp();
    }, function() {
       $(this)
       .removeClass('active')
       .next('.content').slideDown();
 });
```

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benblustey/JeabZ/)

Any Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap your functions in the `toggle` function around, it should give you the effect you want -

```
$(function(){
    $('#services .content').hide();
    $('.header').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) $(this).addClass('active').next('.content').slideUp();
        else $(this).removeClass('active').next('.content').slideDown();
    });
})
```

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/daCkp/1/

Comment: I had this thought too, but now you have to double-click the initially open ones to close them!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The issue still persists, but on the other elements. This will require the other elements that are showing, two clicks to initiate the toggle.

Comment: No it doesn't. Now you have to click Content1 and Content2 twice to hide it.

Comment: Sorry - I'd missed the other two sliders - I've corrected the answer now

Comment: Works great. The one issue I found was the 'active' class needed to be added to the first line.

I changed the first line to include the 'active' class.
"$('#services .header').addClass('active').next('.content').hide();"

Thanks ipr101!

Comment: @benblustey - Excellent! Pleased it's working now. I'd really appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tg5eZ/

No if/else

```
$(function() {
    $('#services .content').hide();
    $('.header').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('.content').slideToggle();
    })
});
```

I would also set

```
#services .content
```

div style to

```
display:none
```

and remove

```
 $('#services .content').hide();
```

This makes it look better in Opera. When I open jsfiddle you provided I see this div is visible and then it is hidden.